# Can't make wx-widget work with net-beans

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans, wxwidgets

I have 64bit windows 7, and I'm trying to use netbeans 7.3 with wxWidgets. I have instaled MinGW and MSYS, and they work fine (test c++ app under netbeans compile ok).

I'm going throught this tutorial: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MSYS-MinGW

I'm stuck under the line:
wx-config --libs or wx-config --cxxflags

When I run it, this is what I get:
(also I provide my directories and enviroment variables I have set)

[image]

EDIT:
Oh. I forgot to write that setup.h is there, under: C:\WXWIN\lib\gcc_dll\mswu\wx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about this "wx-config" you use (it's not the standard one from wxWidgets itself), but it clearly concatenates the values of `WXWIN` and `WXCFG` environment variables, so the latter should be relative to the former instead of being a full path. I.e. you need to set `WXCFG` to just `gcc_dll\mswu`.