# Can't build test application with WxWIdgets in Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, compiler-errors, wxwidgets

I'm a total c++ Newbie.

I'm trying to build windows aplications with Wx-Widgets under Net Beans.

So far so good. I have instaled everything, configured, build wx-widgets and attached it to the new project - with help of a good man here: [Can't make wx-widget work with net-beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583386/cant-make-wx-widget-work-with-net-beans).

Now I try to build my first app:

```
#include <wx/string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  wxPuts(wxT("A wxWidgets console application"));
}
```

and this is what I get:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is readable so I paste the errors:

```
g++ `C:\WXWIN\wx-config --cxxflags`    -c -g -I../../../WXWIN/include `C:\WXWIN\wx-config --cxxflags` -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
/bin/sh.exe: C:WXWINwx-config: command not found
/bin/sh.exe: C:WXWINwx-config: command not found
In file included from ../../../WXWIN/include/wx/defs.h:21:0,
                 from ../../../WXWIN/include/wx/string.h:25,
                 from main.cpp:1:
../../../WXWIN/include/wx/platform.h:196:22: fatal error: wx/setup.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/xampp/htdocs/WxWwigets_tutorial'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/xampp/htdocs/WxWwigets_tutorial'


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 859ms)
```

Please notice that I have set everything in linker and compiler like ordered: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_using_Netbeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is right in front of you: "command not found". If you use `/bin/sh`, you must use Unix style paths, e.g. `C:/WXWIN/wx-config` instead of DOS paths with the backslashes.

I seriously advise you to get familiar with the environment you're using instead of just following the Wiki instructions without understanding them, otherwise your problems won't be over any time soon.

Comment: Yes, I had it in front of me, just didn't know what to do with it :) Tried C:\WXWIN\ from command line instead of C:/WXWIN/ - Thanx for help. +1.